# Как отбрасывать лишнии нажатия пользователя?

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Пользователь давит на кнопку множество раз, по нажатию оборудование отправляется команда, выполнение команды длительное и по окончанию происходит событие.

Как сделать, чтобы вызовы пришедшие пока не получен результат первого вызова отбрасывались, но по окончанию выполнить крайний ?

Другими словами как отбросить те вызовы которые генерирует пользователь пока выполняется его первый вызов и по завершению первого выполнить крайний пришедший за время выполнения первого?

Comment: А крайний ето который?

Comment: Леня, это который был вызван пользователем  на момент когда поток закончил выполнять первый вызов.

Comment: сделайте переменную для хранения последнего вызова и туда записывайте команду пользователя когда он ее нажимает и первая команда все еще выполняется, когда она заканчивает то выполняйте команду в зависимости от этой переменной

Comment: Да, общий алгоритм мне понятен, интересует как это сделать наиболее лучшим способом. Создавать отдельный поток для выполнения или брать поток из пула для выполнения вызова. И как синхронизировать потоки, и доступ к разделяемым ресурсам. Спрашиваю здесь, так как мое решение мне кажется очень замороченным и возможно есть более простой подход для данного кейса.

Comment: Monitor.TryEnter

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev Лёнь, есть ли возможность накидай пожалуйста код, так будет наиболее понятно.

Comment: `по нажатию оборудование отправляется команда, выполнение команды длительное и по окончанию происходит событие` блокируйте кнопку при первом нажании и разбокируйте когда приходит событие.

Comment: _крайний_ - как же это надоело... Надеюсь, это будет последний раз, когда вы пишете столь неграмотно.

Comment: Запомните главное правило этого сайта: одна тема - один вопрос. Не задавайте несколько разных вопросов в одной теме (тем более в комментариях). Взамен создайте несколько тем.

Comment: _Создавать отдельный поток для выполнения или брать поток из пула_ - Пул предназначен для выполнения коротких задач. Если ваша задача выполняется долго, создавайте отдельный поток.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static object m_inputQueue = new object();
public void YourFunc()
{
  // Request the lock.
  if (Monitor.TryEnter(m_inputQueue))
  {
     try
     {
        //Your long action
     }
     finally
     {
        // Ensure that the lock is released.
        Monitor.Exit(m_inputQueue);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: А чем это лучше простого `lock`?

Comment: ничем, разве что можно выйти из блокировки не в жестко заданный момент, а по условию например

Comment: 1 строчка кода против десятка

Comment: ну это почти то же самое, что [lock statement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement)

Comment: @tym32167 обычный lock просто блокирует, а тут либо блок (если свободно), либо else(или ничего как в примере). Те игнор других вызовов когда 1 выполняется. Не путать с Monitor.Enter

Comment: Да я понял, вы пытаетесь учесть многопоточный сценарий. Но это 1) возможно не будет работать если у автора есть асинхронный код 2) будет бесполезно в функции обработки нажатия кнопки, так как эта функция всегда вызывается в UI потоке, то есть в одном и том же потоке. Потому я автору предложил просто блокировать кнопку на время операции, это потокобезопасно.